# A module over a noetherian ring and its dual

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, noetherian

> Let $R$ be a noetherian ring, $M$ an $R$-module and $M^*$ be its dual. Is it true that if $M$ is noetherian then $f(x) = 0$ for all $f \in M^*$ implies $x =0$? How about the other way round?

Ok, so the above is clearly not true.

> How about if I change the condition $M$ is noetherian into $M$ is a submodule of $R^n$ for some $n$?

Comment: What would the "other way around" be ?

Comment: @CaptainLama For this I mean if $f(x) =0$ for all $f \in M^*$ implies $x=0$, then does $M$ have to be noetherian? Moreover, does it have to be a submodule of $R^n$ for some $n$?

Comment: The condition you are looking for is the natural map $M\to M^{**}$ is injective.

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/851485/a-finite-module-over-a-noetherian-ring-is-torsionless-if-and-only-if-it-is-a-sub

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose there is $0\to M\stackrel{\varphi}\to R^n$. Let $\pi_i:R^n\to R$ be the canonical projections. Then $\pi_i\circ\varphi\in M^*$, so $(\pi_i\circ\varphi)(x)=0$. This shows that $\varphi(x)=0$ and since $\varphi$ is injective we get $x=0$.

(A module which is isomorphic to a submodule of a direct product of copies of $R$ is *torsion-less*, that is, the canonical map $M\to M^{**}$ is injective. The converse also holds.)

Answer (score 3):

This is not true, suppose $R=Z$ and $M=Z/n$. The dual of $Z/n$ is trivial.